# [PHP][MYSQL] Not enough memory to open this page

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, xampp

Library Management system

Problem: Admin or library would like to see the borrowing requests from students. However,it cannot show the hundreds requests sometimes.

Environment: XAMPP in localhost, PHP,MYSQL(Mariadb 10.1.21), angularjs as front end framework. You may refer to this for query and db ->
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/asGAdqfK3cP29svgQtBM9F/5#&togetherjs=Kp3I4En96O

JS code:

```
$http.get("GetAllBorrow.php", { params: { "StudentID":""} })
    .then(function(data) {
        console.log(data.data);
        $scope.requests = data.data;
```

PHP code:

```
if(strcmp($_GET["StudentID"] , "") == 0)
{
$sql = //query 1
} else {
    exit('Invalid student');
}
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die (mysql_error());
$data = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $borrowItemID= $row['borrowItemID'];
    $resourceID= $row['resourceID'];
    $borrowingID= $row['borrowingID'];

    include('GetBorrowItem.php');//from query 2 to query 8
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

GetBorrowItem.php code

```
<?php
$str1 = substr ($resourceID,0,2);

if(strcmp($str1, "IN") == 0) {
    $sql2 = //query 2
} else if(strcmp($str1, "BO") == 0) {
    $sql2 = //query 3
} else if (strcmp($str1, "CD") == 0) {
    $sql2 = //query 4
} else if (strcmp($str1, "MG") == 0) {
    $sql2 = //query 5
} else if (strcmp($str1, "EB") == 0) {
    $sql2 = //query 6
} else if (strcmp($str1, "FL") == 0) {
    $sql2 = //query 7
} else if (strcmp($str1, "DC") == 0) {
     $sql2 = //query 8
} else{
    die ("There is no such item!");
}

if (!mysqli_query($conn,$sql2)) {
printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn));}

while($row2 =  mysqli_fetch_array($result2,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $LineDataDetails = $row2;
}

header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
$LineDataDetails =  json_encode($LineDataDetails);

echo $LineDataDetails;?>
```

I have solved this problem for almost two weeks but Still cannot find the solutions.
Here are the things I have done:

1. Suspected because retrieve too much data at once-> Deleted some data in database -> Result: It can show but sometimes cannot
2. Heavy debugging on one line by one line -> It just appear blank(retrieve nothing from database) -> Suspected code problem but it did used for sometimes, the bug just happened after two months
3. When debugging, found there is one error -> not enough memory to open this page (when would like to retrieve data from borrowItems)

Comment: The db-fiddle that I shared is an almost similar environment that I have created so there is o bug there.The only difference with original is higher data. Query is same

Comment: There are 916 rows returned for first query

Comment: Did you try and move the code from `include('GetBorrowItem.php');` into the loop?, if your doing that 1k times (also setting that header and ouputing json [which should be breaking your js]) and setting `$data[] = $row;` which is not used you might encounter issues.

Comment: Really you should be putting `$LineDataDetails` into `$data` with its associated row and then outputting that.

Comment: I had just tried but it seems no difference =(. Yes, I need to as the admin need to see the items with the requests

Comment: In fact, the console show that it just reach before mysqli_query. It can show what the query is but not perform it.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your PHP code with the below code.

```
if(strcmp($_GET["StudentID"] , "") == 0)
{
$sql = //query 1
} else {
    exit('Invalid student');
}
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die (mysql_error());
$data = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $borrowItemID= $row['borrowItemID'];
    $resourceID= $row['resourceID'];
    $borrowingID= $row['borrowingID'];

     $str1 = substr ($resourceID,0,2);

    if(strcmp($str1, "IN") == 0) {
        $sql2 = //query 2
    } else if(strcmp($str1, "BO") == 0) {
        $sql2 = //query 3
    } else if (strcmp($str1, "CD") == 0) {
        $sql2 = //query 4
    } else if (strcmp($str1, "MG") == 0) {
        $sql2 = //query 5
    } else if (strcmp($str1, "EB") == 0) {
        $sql2 = //query 6
    } else if (strcmp($str1, "FL") == 0) {
        $sql2 = //query 7
    } else if (strcmp($str1, "DC") == 0) {
         $sql2 = //query 8
    } else{
        die ("There is no such item!");
    }

    $result2=mysqli_query($conn,$sql2) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        while($row2 =  mysqli_fetch_array($result2,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
          array_push($data,$row2);
    }


}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Hope this will help..!

Comment: Hi! There is still same.=(..No error but there is no request retrieve

Comment: echo $sql2 before $result2. then check $sql2 generated query in phpmyadmin for the output. Let me know the if there is any output generated from this query.

Comment: After put echo $sql2 before $result 2, there is query being read( shown in browser console)but after few seconds the page cannot display--> (Aw,Snap Something went wrong whilee displaying this page) as well as debugging connection was closed. Btw, how to check  $sql2 generated query in phpmyadmin for the output?

Comment: Correction: "Not enough memory to open this page"